# Trying to toggle style CSS link "href" on click Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, toggle, href

Trying to do a dark-mode toggle on click of element

1. toggle div class = .dark__mode
2. css link class = .css-link
3. css link href variable = style__old

I am learning jquery and i think there is a major problem with reasoning and structure of code

**The link href changes at first but doesn't change back**

Please help and or if using a checkbox option is better

```
window.onload = function(){

    var  style__old = $(".css-link").attr("href");

    $(".dark__mode").click(function(){

            if (style__old == "css/style.css"){
                var style__new = style__old.replace("style.css","dark-mode.css");
                $(".css-link").attr("href", style__new);
            }
            else
            if (style__old == "css/dark-mode.css"){
                style__old.replace("dark-mode.css","style.css");
                $(".css-link").attr("href", "style__old");
            }
    }

);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you're using of dynamically changing the loaded stylesheet is not very reliable.

A much better approach is to put all the relevant styles in to the page, in separate stylesheets, then `toggle()` a class on a low level element, such as the `body`, and hang all your selectors off that.

In practice it would look something like this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.dark__mode').on('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').toggleClass('dark');
  })
});
```

```css
/* Normal layout */
div { color: #0C0; }
a { color: #C00; }

/* Dark layout */
body.dark {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #FFF;
}
body.dark div { color: #CCC; }
body.dark a { color: #CC0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="dark__mode">Toggle</a>
<div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</p>
  <a href="#">Amet consectetur adipcing elit</a>
</div>
```